# Function accept type argument

Tags: generics, rust, trait-objects, prost

I am working on a client server application where i send messages to / from each as protocol buffers using the rust crate prost.  currently i have a generic `send_message` function that can take any struct that implements the `prost::Message` trait.  I'm trying to create a similar function for reading a type that implements `prost::Message`.  I believe the issue is that `decode` which is a method for types that implement `prost::Message` is an associated function and not an instance method. the actual instance of the object that implements `prost::Message` is created within the function.

Im wondering if there is a way to make a generic `read_message` function that can accept any type that implements `prost::Message` and use the associated function `decode` on that type.

This is my current `send_message` function:

```
pub fn send_message<M>(message: M, stream: &mut TcpStream) -> io::Result<()>
where
    M: Message,
{
    let length = message.encoded_len() as i32;
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(length as usize);
    message.encode(&mut buf)?;
    stream.write_all(&length.to_le_bytes())?;
    stream.write_all(&buf)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

and right now i have two `read_TYPE_message` functions:

```
pub fn read_response_message(stream: &mut TcpStream) -> io::Result<message::Response> {
    let mut len_buf = [0u8; 4];
    stream.read_exact(&mut len_buf)?;
    let len = i32::from_le_bytes(len_buf);
    println!("Incoming message length: {}", len);
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; len as usize];
    stream.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    let response = message::Response::decode(&mut buf.as_slice())?;
    Ok(response)
}

fn read_request_message(stream: &mut TcpStream) -> io::Result<message::Request> {
    let mut len_buf = [0u8; 4];
    stream.read_exact(&mut len_buf)?;
    let len = i32::from_le_bytes(len_buf);
    println!("Incoming message length: {}", len);
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; len as usize];
    stream.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    let user_input = message::Request::decode(&mut buf.as_slice())?;
    Ok(user_input)
}
```

When i tried the below:

```
fn read_message<M: Message>(msg: M, stream: &mut TcpStream) -> io::Result<M> {
    let mut len_buf = [0u8; 4];
    stream.read_exact(&mut len_buf)?;
    let len = i32::from_le_bytes(len_buf);
    println!("Incoming message length: {}", len);
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; len as usize];
    stream.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    let pb_msg = msg::decode(&mut buf.as_slice())?;
    Ok(pb_msg)
}
```

I get the error

```
failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `msg` use of undeclared crate or module `msg`
```

i was hoping to be able use the function something like this:

```
let input = read_message(message::Request, &mut stream)?;
let input = read_message(message::Response, &mut stream)?;
```

Comment: `msg::decode(...)`, you cannot call static method over variable, compiler thinks it as a path, this explains the error message you've got. You need to it like this `M::decode(&mut buf.as_slice)`

Comment: thank you @ÖmerErden, i believe this gets me closer. now im struggling to see how i use that approach to then dispatch to returning the appropriate type that implements `M` i.e. `M::decode(&mut buf.as_slice)` can return either a `Response` or a `Request`

Comment: You are already in generic scope, your concrete type is `M` which can be `Request` or `Response` not both, so either define  your type like `let pb_msg: M = ...` or let compiler infer it. Here is a similar code to yours [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c787eb0fad5658ab29d81e42c78c6aeb)

Comment: that worked. thanks so much!